# Как отослать изображения через AJAX, которые были загружены на страницу через URL c другого сайта

Tags: ajax, php, html, javascript

Как отослать изображения через AJAX, которые были загружены на страницу через URL c другого сайта ? То есть. Я ввожу URL в поле и в форме создается img. Как это img отослать через AJAX ?

Comment: При чем тут PHP? Он на стороне сервера работает.

Если уж и использовать PHP, то тогда отправлять на сервер URL картинки, а скрипт пусть через тот же `file_get_content()` загружает картинку и потом складывает в нужно место. ИМХО так даже проще, чем гнать бинарные данные

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через JS никак, если конечно на другом сервер не включен CORS, либо передать на сервер src и через cURL скачать её.